# Trouble with dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I got a little problem, let me introduce:

I have SSD with win already installed. I boot ubuntu 19 from flash and install alongside windows 10. At the end of installation it gives me error: `cant install grub boot loader`, so I chose a sdb (the disk where is win 10 installed on).

And now it directly boot me in Windows.
So I tried:

1. Add `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` it didnt help.
2. Change in `BIOS LEGACY+UEFI` to `UEFI` - and it keeps returning me in BIOS.
3. Find out if Linux was **really** instaled - It is installed.

So, what I've done badly?

If you know, please, feel free to answer, I'm glad for every answer. Thanks

Comment: If Windows is UEFI, it then has an ESP - efi system partition. So UEFI install of Ubuntu would use that and give no error. Error then is probably from not having a bios_grub partition for a BIOS boot install of Ubuntu. But you really want a UEFI install. You can use Boot-Repair's advanced mode from Ubuntu live installer, to install the Ubuntu UEFI version of grub. To install Boot-Repair to live installer: use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @Zdeněk Krast So we can see the partitioning of your drive(s),, please run `parted -l` , copy the result, and paste it into your question by clicking [edit]. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].